# WP_Query split into two different DIV

Tags: wordpress

this is my layout for Blog List
[image]

How can I split WP_Query within two different DIV. I am trying to achieve this with following code

```
<div class="container">
        <?php
        $args = array(  
            'post_type' => 'post',
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
            <div class="col-md-8"> <?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); 
        ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your current format, you've got two options. You can either do it with CSS or with PHP.

CSS would be the easiest, you can just make use of the [`::nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class. If you're using the latest Bootstrap, you can just flip the `flex-direction` of every `2n` rows.

```
.row:nth-child(2n){
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Here's a quick example: https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/RwRRooy

The other option would be to check even/odd iterations with the [Modulo Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) and physically adjust the layout based on the result. Something like the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <?php
        $args = array(  
            'post_type' => 'post',
        );
        
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
        $count = 0;
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); $count++ ?>
            <div class="row">
                <?php if( $count % 2 === 0 ){ ?>
                    <div class="col-md-8"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <div class="col-md-4"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
                    <div class="col-md-8"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); 
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, It is working perfectly, I choose first option
 
 .row:nth-child(2n){
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Pagination Parameters on the [documentation of the WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/), you see there's a parameter for offset. Say you'd like to display 4 posts in the first div, you'd just use the same query with an offset of 4 in the second div.